# Why a file always missing after build in Intellij with maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I have been stuck in the problem for quite a while.I use Intellij and maven not very long.
the problem like this:

the version of my Intellij is 12.1.4,I am making a project of Spring MVC with maven.So the output directory is 'target' in the project workspace.I have a mybatis xml file in my path.

once I found that the xml file did not change autoautomaticly in the target directory.so    I delete it in the target directory.after I have done this,I rebuild the project,but the file never appear any more.

why?how should I do?

Comment: when you build the project using maven from the command line ("mvn clean install") is the file created correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put that file in `src/main/resources`, maven copies all the resources from default resource directory to `target/classes`